# Docker - Installing Composer /bin/sh: 1: php: not found curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, dockerfile

Hello I am creating a dockerfile for my laravel project. This is it so far:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
FROM nginx
FROM node:8
MAINTAINER zachary tyhacz

# does not install mysql
# mysql is outside container

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/public
COPY . /var/www/public

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

RUN npm install
RUN composer install

# sets up the database
CMD php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

# resets configuration files
CMD php artisan config:cache

# refreshes routes
CMD php artisan route:cache

# enables serve
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=436

EXPOSE 8080/udp
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
EXPOSE 80/udp
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 436/tcp
EXPOSE 436/udp
```

upon docker tag to create an image, it gets to this instruction:

`Step 6/22 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

and it throws this error and stops.

```
/bin/sh: 1: php: not found
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. I think it could be a permissions issue or a directory issue.

Thanks anyone for any suggestions in helping me out

also, my reference in helping me create this dockerfile is this:
https://buddy.works/guides/laravel-in-docker

Comment: You can more or less only have one FROM and one CMD, and you’re building from a `node:8` image base without PHP.

Comment: There's no "more or less", only one of each is permitted, with the most recently defined taking precedence. Also, installing more than one service per container is generally considered bad practice. Look at something like docker-compose or kubernetes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one base image using `FROM` in a Dockerfile. Basically, that tells docker what to start with. In your case, you have several `FROM`s, so it appears that Docker simply takes the last one you give it, in this case `node:8`. So PHP is never being installed.

To fix this issue, you'll need to pick a single base image (for example php), and install your other dependencies on top of that, so you could manually install nginx and node on top of the php image using `RUN`. You may also want to consider building a separate nginx image. This is considered good practice to separate your services into different images when possible.

Also, instead of using multiple `CMD` entries, use a small startup shell script. For example

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
exec php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=436
```

Put that in a script called `start.sh` or something like that, then in your Dockerfile, use

```
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

Then, you'll probably also want to start a second container for your nginx service. You could do this manually using docker run, but I suggest checking out docker-compose. It helps you build and run multiple containers at once.